# LARAVEL DOMPDF: How do I know when DOMPDF automatically breaks the page?

Tags: html, laravel, dompdf

First of all I would like to thank DOMPDF.
How do I know when DOMPDF automatically breaks the page?

When using rowspan, the page break automatically causes an error. Please see in the picture.

[image]

Comment: You should add the code for your View and the call to the dompdf rendering function. However, in my experience this package is better than dompdf: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy